# White Screen of Death on WP admin

Tags: wordpress

I can’t connect anymore to wp admin, there’s a blank screen each time I try to connect like I always did on the back office.

Some pages of my website aren’t working either, only the ones that have forms for some reason.

I tried to recover my website, recover the database, delete the plugins, delete the theme, I gave permissions, nothing worked.

The only thing I didn’t try, is to fix what WP Debug said :

Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home/clementiri/clem2017/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/menu.php on line 278

—

```
$menu_order = apply_filters( ‘menu_order’, $menu_order );
$menu_order = array_flip( $menu_order ); (278)
$default_menu_order = array_flip( $default_menu_order );
```

Do you have an idea please ?

Comment: Maybe your WP core files got corrupted somehow? Try following these [instructions to upload a clean version of WP to your server](https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update) (steps 1 and 2) and try logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

Just try following steps:

> 1. Make a backup of your WP installation.
> 2. Download a new WP from http://wordpress.org/latest.zip, if you want an old version download from https://wordpress.org/download/releases/
> 3. Replace all other files except wp-content folder and 2 files; .htacesss, wp-config.php

It should work. if you still find any error please reply the same thread.